# Can itemprop from one div refer to items in another div?

Tags: microdata

I am struggling to solve what I had guessed would be an easy problem. I am not sure if it's solely a Schema.org issue, or if I am failing to understand the syntax of divs.

I am adding markup to an article using the schema article markup:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/article">
```

This `div` encompasses all of the content on the page, and I close it at the bottom of the page.

Nested within that `div`, a few paragraphs down, is another `div`, which is `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EducationalOrganization">` and within that `div` is `<span itemprop="http://schema.org/audience"> parents </span>`.

I would like to know how I need to markup the word parents to indicate that the "audience" property should be applied to the "article" itemtype.

I would post all of my HTML, but there's a lot of text. Hopefully this makes sense to someone. I am pretty sure all of my tags are formatted correctly by HTML standards.

Comment: Can you perhaps post the URL to the page that you have marked up so that we can see the HTML and the schemas that you have inserted?

Comment: You ask about the Microdata syntax, and it’s unrelated which specific vocabulary you use (in your case, schema.org). So I retagged your question and changed its title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is not possible.

In your described example, `audience` is in scope of and therefore applies to `EducationalOrganization`. As `EducationalOrganization` doesn’t define an `audience` property, it’s an invalid use of the schema.org vocabulary.

You can workaround by not nesting *everything* in `Article` (resp. don’t nest the "parents" part in the `EducationalOrganization`). Use the [`itemref` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#attr-itemref) instead to connect all the relevant pieces together.

See the question on Webmasters SE: [linking several separated schema.org `<div>`s together?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/52570/17633)

Another possibilty: Don’t use the markup on "parents". Instead, duplicate the information in a `meta` element, included in the `Article` (but not in `EducationalOrganization`). With Microdata, `meta` [can be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax) in the `body`.

```
<meta itemprop="http://schema.org/audience" content="parents" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "subject" property like this:

```
<p item="vcard" id="me">
   I'm <span itemprop="fn">Philip Jägenstedt</span>.
</p>
<!-- stuff -->
<a itemprop="url" subject="me"   href="http://foolip.org/">foolip.org</a>.
```

Extract from: http://blog.foolip.org/2009/08/23/microformats-vs-rdfa-vs-microdata/

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's based on a really early draft of Microdata. There's no `subject` attribute (or for that matter `item` attribute) in modern microdata. Spec is at http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/microdata/master/Overview.html#htmlpropertiescollection Such references are achieved the other way round, from the `itemscope`d element using the `itemref` attribute.